# Automatic CRL files converter

Tags: bash, linux, openssl

In my job we use our internal CA, which runs on a Windows server. When I want to use its CRL on a Linux machine I have to do these steps:

1. download root CA and intermediate CAs
2. covert them to x509
3. merge into one file (`CRL.pem`)

For this I wrote the small script below, which I run automatically by timer unit (`cron` on systems without `systemd`) once a day.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

crls=(RootCA IntermediateCA IntermediateCA2)
new_crl="newcrl.pem"
crl_temp=$(mktemp -q -d /tmp/pullcrl.XXXXX)
crl_dir="/etc/pki/tls/misc"


for crl in ${crls[@]}; do
  if curl -s http://url_of_crls/${crl}.crl -o ${crl_temp}/${crl}.crl; then
    openssl crl -in ${crl_temp}/${crl}.crl -inform DER -out ${crl_temp}/${crl}.pem
  else
    echo "Download a crl file failed!"
    exit 1
  fi
done

cat ${crl_temp}/*.pem > ${crl_temp}/${new_crl}

mv ${crl_temp}/${new_crl} ${crl_dir}/${new_crl}
```

Could I do something better?

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> for crl in ${crls[@]}; do
> ```

It's a good habit to always double-quote array expansions.

Cleaning up the temp directory after a successful run would be a nice touch (or do away with it altogether; see below).

> ```
> cat ${crl_temp}/*.pem > ${crl_temp}/${new_crl}
> mv ${crl_temp}/${new_crl} ${crl_dir}/${new_crl}
> ```

I assume you're doing this to get atomic replacement?  It only works if /tmp and /etc are on the same filesystem.  If they're not, you could get an empty destination file when (for example) the target is full.  Consider creating a working directory under /etc to be certain.

You could be more concise using `cd` and brace expansion and bash's own error handling (via `set -euxo pipefail`):

```
set -euxo pipefail

cd /etc/pki/tls/misc
temp=$( mktemp -p . )

for url in http://…blahblah…/{RootCA,IntermediateCA,IntermediateCA2}.crl ; do 
    curl $url | openssl crl -in - -inform DER
done > $temp
mv $temp newcrl.pem
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the hints. Im using the `rm` cleaning at the end, just copy and paste issue. I thought about `set -e`, but I need to tell an other script, started on different time, that the result was failure - my mistake, I should have done the note about that in code. (I expect to that by writing a note into a file.). The other things looks really tasty :) Thanks again.

Comment: I like the part with curl and the pipe. It works fine in _GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release_ but in _GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release_ I got this error `(23) Failed writing body`.

Comment: that's not bash causing the failure.  It's a different curl, or a different openssl, or a .curlrc exists that changes how curl works, or one of the two commands is aliased to have different behaviour.

Comment: You are right, I found out it already. But due to that, isn't much more safely, just download all CLRs files and then convert them in separate way? Your example is pretty good, but I don't want to tune system by system that works.

Comment: The only safety change is moving temp dir to /etc.   Using pipe for curl isn't safer, it's just cleaner because fewer temporary files.

Comment: Note that unchecked `cd` (without `set -e`) is a common dangerous anti-pattern.  It's clear that you understand the importance, but might be worth pointing that up for passing readers!

Answer (score 1):

I merge my previous code with hints provided by [@Oh My Goodness](/a/229126/206203).

- I excluded the variable `clr_dir`. The code thanks to is much more readable.
- And I moved temp dir to the same filesystem as is final destination of new CRL.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail
cd /etc/pki/tls/misc

crls=(RootCA IntermediateCA IntermediateCA2)
crl_temp=$(mktemp -p .)


for crl in "${crls[@]}"; do
  curl -s http://url_of_crls/crl/"${crl}".crl -o "${crl}".crl
  openssl crl -in "${crl}".crl -inform DER
  rm -rf "${crl}".crl
done > "$crl_temp"

mv "$crl_temp" CRL.pem
```

I omitted the pipe for curl due to problems which it caused on systems with curl version 7.29.0. (It works fine on version 7.58.0.)